# How to retrieve latest model object of a logged in user who has already submitted the form?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I tried something like this

```
customer=Customer.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).latest('first_name', 'last_name')
customer.first_name
```

However this fetches me the old data of the logged in user from first_name field submitted via the form (in an earlier submission). (Assuming the logged in user did 3 submissions it fetches me data of 1st submission and not the most recent one.)

I read about latest() method and implemented this

```
customer=Customer.objects.latest('id')
```

but as we know this will only render the last submission details not necessarily of the user who has logged in.

Here is my model.py for reference

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    customerReg=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=None)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=None)
```

So, how would I query that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the relation between `User` and `Customer` is [`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), you can simply use:

```
try:
    customer = user.customer
except:
    customer = None
```

If it was a `ForeignKey` relation, then you could use:

```
customer = request.user.customer_set.last()
```

Comment: After a thought I guess a foreign key would be better for my database. So thanks for going a step extra.

Answer (score 1):

Use `descend` ordering to get `latest` model object by user :

```
customer = Customer.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).order_by('-id')
```